# Problem: article title/ thumbnail photo does not showon Facebook when sharing

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, facebook

I've looked at similar issues on this forum but can't find answer I need.

Basically Problem is article title/ thumbnail photo does not show on Facebook when sharing. This is a massive problem for [my website](http://www.hillingdonishere.co.uk) as most traffic comes this way.

Articles are K2 items.

I know next to nothing about code! Facebook debugger tells me this...

> http://www.hillingdonishere.co.uk/index.php/articles/item/283-west-drayton-women-s-christmas-campaign-to-help-homeless-snowballs-as-nearly-3-000-aid-project' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
>
> Warning
>   Curl Error : WRITE_ERROR Error while processing content unencoding: invalid block type
>
> Warning
>   Errors That Must Be Fixed
>
> Object Missing a Required ValueObject at URL 'http://www.hillingdonishere.co.uk/index.php/articles/item/283-west-drayton-women-s-christmas-campaign-to-help-homeless-snowballs-as-nearly-3-000-aid-project' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
>
> When shared, this is what will be included
>
> Warning
>   fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog. Otherwise, the default app id( 966242223397117 ) will be assigned.
>
> Based on included and inferred properties, the below preview is what users will see when they share this URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need add Opengraph informations in joomla to work with Facebook.

See this reference page to know more about OpenGraph:

http://ogp.me

This plugins to Joomla works fine:

http://e-max.it/joomla-plugins/easy-open-graph

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/phoca-open-graph

****** UPDATE:
I have another plugin working in this site:
http://www.sindha.org.br/index.php/blog/gastronomia/4254-a-essencia-dos-temperos

You can see this plugin in: 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-bookmarking/14094

This puglin create a share button and control Open Graph tags fine.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Max, thank you very much indeed for your answer.
That was very kind of you to take the time and it's much appreciated.
I tried phoca already but did not work for me. It also caused problem with other modules. I haven't tried e-max. Do you have a website URL that uses this plugin that I'd be able to look at please? Do you have free version or the 'pay with a tweet' (which by the way I don't understand what they mean)
Also, have you used JFB Connect by SourceCoast? It's paid for module&does various other things but mentions specifically the open graph solution.
Many thanks, James

Comment: I update my answare.

Comment: thank you again very much Max. I really appreciate your help.   Ihave tried ITP social plugin as you suggested.  It does help but there are some strange errors with it still. It now shows a photo, whereas before there was no photo. However, the image is now the wrong one! Sometimes the title is wrong as well.  I have tried 3 other plug ins and all do the same thing. Same errors I mean.  Is there any solution to this that you can suggest please?  Again, you're very kind to help. Thank you in advance. James

Comment: Did you try clear facebook cache from this page you are do tests in: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Hi Max. Yes I did try this. Someone else suggested there are 2 og image files due to k2 component.

Said take that of k2 buy dint know how.  Any thoughts?

▶ Show quoted text

Comment: Inspect your code in page: http://www.hillingdonishere.co.uk/index.php/articles/item/283-west-drayton-women-s-christmas-campaign-to-help-homeless-snowballs-as-nearly-3-000-aid-project 

should be ok:

<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.hillingdonishere.co.uk/media/k2/items/cache/d382bd8ae87d9139df6458192532657c_L.jpg">